# What is non-expansion work?

Tags: thermodynamics, free-energy

I learnt that Gibbs free energy is the maximum amount of non-expansion work.
But the phrase non expansion work confuses me. Work is defined as pressure times change in volume. If there is no expansion, how can work be done?

Comment: It's when I stair-climb the Willis Tower in Chicago each November for the Shirley Ryan AbilityLab. I certainly don't expand during the climb, but I do work against Earth's gravity.

Comment: You do have to push aside the air you encounter as you rise that takes extra energy. Try climbing up in a tank of water with negative buoyancy. This explanation of Gibbs free energy is very non general.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Pressure-Volume work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(thermodynamics)#Pressure-volume_work) is a type of mechanical work .
There are also [non-mechanical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(thermodynamics)#Non-mechanical_forms_of_work) forms of work where in pressure and volume terms are not involved .
The most famous example is [electrical work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_work) . The work done to move electrical charges ( like motion of electrons in a conductor) comes under this category .

Comment: Another example is the stirring of a liquid in a tank